# Duplication in string capitalization. Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, capitalization

I'm a Ruby newbie and I need your help with the below:

> The task is to write a function that would return the following result:
>
> ```
>    "Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"
> ```
>
> It also needs to work on "Two words"

The problem I have is with a letter 'L' as the function seems to be capitalizing both of them within a string.

Here is my code:

```
def wave(str)
  str.each do |word|
    count = -1

    word.length.times do
      count += 1
      puts word.gsub(word[count],word[count].capitalize)
    end
  end
end

wave("hello")
```

Comment: In your method definition you've `def wave(str)` suggesting that a string will be the input of the method. However when handling the `str` variable and calling the *wave* method we see you provide an array with a single string. My question is, is the input meant to be an array or a string? If an array what would be the expected output if it contained no strings, or more than one string?

Comment: Johan it should be a string. Apologies! Also there is a further test this function needs to pass and that is "Two words".

Comment: In that case I would change the argument name to `def wave(*words)` which makes it more clear that a list of words is passed. This syntax also allows you to call the method using `wave("word1", "word2", "etc...")`, without wrapping the arguments in an array. For more info about this have a look at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array-2FHash+Argument and https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a please solve my homework question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
str = 'hi fi'
p str.size.times.map{ str.dup }.map.with_index{ |s, i| s[i] = s[i].upcase; s unless s[i] == ' '}.compact
#=> ["Hi fi", "hI fi", "hi Fi", "hi fI"]
```

Here is how it works:

First builds an array containing n times the word, where n is the word length:

```
str.size.times.map{ str.dup } #=> ["hello", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello"]
```

Note that `.dup` is required in order to be able to modify each element of the array without affect all elements.

Then, map with index ([Enummerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index)) to upcase the letter at index. Finally returns `s` unless the current character is a space, in that case it returns `nil`, that's why `.compact` is called.

That's the modified OP method, no need to pass an array of string as argument:

```
def wave(str)
  str.length.times do |n|
    str_dup = str.dup
    str_dup[n] = str_dup[n].capitalize
    puts str_dup unless str_dup[n] == ' '
  end
end

wave('hi fi')
#=> Hi fi
#=> hI fi
#=> hi Fi
#=> hi fI
```

Comment: And it does work on the given example. However, function will not work if you test for "Two words" which is something I forgot to mention in the above :-/

Comment: str = 'hello word'
str.size.times.map{ str.dup }.map.with_index{ |s, i| s[i] = s[i].upcase; s }    I get 
the following: Should return: '["Two words", "tWo words", "twO words", "two Words", "two wOrds", "two woRds", "two worDs", "two wordS"]' -  Expected: ["Two words", "tWo words", "twO words", "two Words", "two wOrds", "two woRds", "two worDs", "two wordS"], instead got: ["Two words", "tWo words", "twO words", "two words", "two Words", "two wOrds", "two woRds", "two worDs", "two wordS"]

Comment: The task is from Codewars

Comment: Analyzing the above code will need to avoid getting : "two words" between "twO words", "two Words" so the space will need to be ignored

Comment: Yes, upcase the space result in unchanged word, try changing this way: `str.size.times.map{ str.dup }.map.with_index{ |s, i| s[i] = s[i].upcase; s unless s[i] == ' ' }.compact`

Comment: That's brilliant and passes all the tests. I will try to break your code down to little bits and study carefully. Many thanks!

Comment: There's no need to mention that you are editing your answer. Nor is there a reason to keep your original answer if you or someone else comes up with an improvement. Imagine you are writing a book and send out a draft to reviewers. On the basis of comments received you rewrite some sections. Obviously, you don't keep what you had and show the new-and-improved text, as that would be a disservice to readers. I suggest you take the same approach at SO. Similarly, if you wish to acknowledge and thank a reader for a suggestion, the place to do that is in a comment, keeping the answer clean.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
def rep_it(word)
  Array.new(word.size) {|i| word [0,i] << word[i].upcase << word[i+1..-1].to_s}
end

rep_it 'hello'
  #=> ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]
```

[Array::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-c-new) works well here here because the needed character index is built into the method.

When `i == word.size-1`, `<< word[word.size]`(`<< nil`) would raise an exception; hence (the trick) `<< nil.to_s` (`<< ''`). (See [NilClass#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/NilClass.html#method-i-to_s).) Longer, but arguably clearer, would be to write the block as follows:

```
{|i| word [0,i] << word[i].upcase << ((i < word.size-1) ? word[i+1..-1] : '')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with

```
s = "hello there"
s.each_char.with_index.with_object([]) do |(l,i),arr|
  arr << "#{s}" and arr.last[i] = l if l.upcase! 
end
#=> ["Hello there", 
#     "hEllo there", 
#     "heLlo there", 
#     "helLo there", 
#     "hellO there", 
#     "hello There", 
#     "hello tHere", 
#     "hello thEre", 
#     "hello theRe", 
#    "hello therE"]
```

If a character can be upcased (e.g. `/[a-z]/`) `if l.upcase!` then push a copy of str into the `Array` (`arr << "#{s}"`) and then replace the character at `str[i]` with the now upcased version (`arr.last[i] = l`)